# Will it affect signal strength to locate a wireless router (both 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz) inside a closet?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, signal-strength

If a wireless router is located in the center of the house, does it matter if it's being put inside a closet instead of over the counter? That is, while it takes less room in and look nicer, will it also reduce the WiFi's signal strength?

Inside an open closet:

[image: Router in an open closet]

Inside a closed closet (imagine if it was completely closed):

[image: Router in a closed closet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All signals are attenuated to *some* degree by obstacles. This is a simple fact of physics.

How much signal is lost depends on the material and wifi band.

- Metals will likely block *all* the signal. A metal cupboard will likely act like a faraday cage and effectively isolate the wifi signal so that nearly no signal is seen outside.
- Woods may absorb some of the signals, depending on their density, thickness and moisture content. How much they attenuate would be difficult to say except that WiFi is usually capable of going through a couple of walls at 10-15m range with a usable signal at the end, you are adding yet another barrier, so you'll have to test if it is okay.
- 5GHz is more attenuated by obstructions and range than 2.4GHz. At a given range the 2.4GHz signal may be better, but the data rate would be slower than is capable with 5GHz.

At the end of the day you'll have to test for your particular conditions and situation.

If you currently get great signal everywhere with the router outside of the cupboard, then you may well get a good signal from inside. It may well be fine, it might not. The only person who can actually find out is you.